# How to save image to specific directory in p5.js

Tags: javascript, image, p5.js

I wanna save image to "../assets/" in in p5.js 
I tried this

```
save("../assets/", "test.png")
```

but don't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: The documentation of p5.js save method is here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/save

Comment: Can you be more specific than saying it didn't work? What happened when you ran this code? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: `````
Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
`````
This is error message. I can understand the meaning but how to solve?